# How to change/insert a picture/photo that appears besides my display name?

Tags: support, avatar

The question says it all? My quest led me to gravatar. But I am unable to insert a photo/picture of my choice and connect it to my TeX.SX account.

**EDIT:** I have uploaded a photo at gravatar.com and registered a primary e-mail address. When I log in to TeX.SX using that mail id, I expected that the image would come properly. But it is not happening. Some help here will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your Gravatar account using the same e-mail address as the one you've registered here?

Comment: I think [Changing and keeping a user avatar/icon](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1607/changing-and-keeping-a-user-avatar-icon) will answer that. Please tell us if you need further support. Otherwise this question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @JosephWright I am using the same email id which registered at gravatar. **To Martin** I am unable to find a solution from the link you provided. I have edited the question for more clarity and expecting help.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Did you use the same capitalization of your e-mail address? Afaik, it matters for gravatars.

Comment: @doncherry, Yes, I used the same one. But not effective.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Is your email shown correctly in the email field of your profile?

Comment: @Caramdir Actually there I have given another mail ID. But for logging in I use the gravatar primary mail ID. Will it make the difference? I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To choose the Gravatar, the e-mail from your profile is taken (rather than the e-mail you use for login). So you need to make sure that the e-mail address in your profile and your Gravatar accounts match.

(I suppose this is done this way for two reasons: to give you more flexibility to change the e-mail address; and to make it work for everyone who uses an OpenID login.)